# Background image not showing CSS, tried everything

Tags: css

I have the image in the same directory as the `scss`.

I tried doing everything:

```
background-image: url("day.jpg");
background-image: url("/day.jpg");
background-image: url(day.jpg);
background-image: url(/day.jpg);
```

But still not able to show my image. What could be the reason?

Comment: Hi can you post your HTML and more of your CSS code so we can replicate the issue?  BTW the correct format would be `background-image: url("day.jpg"); `

Comment: *I have the image in the same directory as the scss* Browsers don't understand *scss*. What sort of asset build tool/stack converts your SCSS to CSS? What tool moves your images to the publishing location?

Comment: Did you check the network panel of your dev tools to see if a request for the image is even happening? Thats the first thing g I would do and then move on to seeing if it is an element sizing issue.

Comment: @zero298 Thanks for the idea. Seems like there is no request.

Comment: Could you try an absolute address for the background-image (https:// or http:// depending on how you are calling things) and see if anything is shown. It sounds though as though this bit of CSS isn't even being called in which case please make a minimal code example in a snippet which shows the problem.